# How to fetch content's color from a dynamic table using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web, screen-scraping

I wanted to fetch color of text from a dynamic table. This table is being loaded using some API therefore i am not able to find this element using Xpath.

The website is https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/coffs-harbour_159102/schweppes-ken-howard-showcase-cup_913723/#OddsComparison

Following is the table i want to fetch [click to see the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsLht.png)

I was able to fetch the contents but now i want to fetch the colors of those small graphs shown in left side (red, green and grey). I know the getCssValue method but it wont work as the table is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some time working on this, I was able to get the information that you requested. 
The technique that I used was, first, to close the dialog if it displayed. Then, I got the number of records that the table displayed and had `selenium` scroll to our element using the `scrollIntoView()` method. 
I was able to get the `bonusBet` color and position.

**MAIN PROGRAM - For Reference**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver as ChromeDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as DriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as DriverConditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import time

def get_chrome_driver():
    """This sets up our Chrome Driver and returns it as an object"""
    path_to_chrome = "F:\Selenium_Drivers\Windows_Chrome85_Driver\chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    
    # Browser is displayed in a custom window size
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1500,1000")
    
    return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chrome,
                            options = chrome_options)

    
def wait_displayed(driver : ChromeDriver, xpath: str, int = 5):
        try:
            DriverWait(driver, int).until(
                DriverConditions.presence_of_element_located(locator = (By.XPATH, xpath))
            )
        except:
            raise WebDriverException(f'Timeout: Failed to find {xpath}')
        
        
def is_displayed(driver : ChromeDriver, xpath: str, int = 5):
        try:
            webElement = DriverWait(driver, int).until(
                DriverConditions.presence_of_element_located(locator = (By.XPATH, xpath))
            )
            return True if webElement != None else False
        except:
            return False
        

def scroll_to_element(driver : ChromeDriver, xpath : str, int = 5):
        try:
            webElement = DriverWait(driver, int).until(
                DriverConditions.presence_of_element_located(locator = (By.XPATH, xpath))
                )
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webElement)
        except:
            raise WebDriverException(f'Timeout: Failed to find element using xpath {xpath}\nResult: Could not scroll')
        
        
def close_dialog(driver : ChromeDriver):
    if(is_displayed(driver, "//div[contains(@class,'CampaignType--popup') and contains(@style, 'display: block;')]//div[@role='dialog']")):
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'CampaignType--popup') and contains(@style, 'display: block;')]//button[@title='Close']").click()
        time.sleep(3)
        if(is_displayed(driver, "//div[contains(@class,'CampaignType--popup') and contains(@style, 'display: block;')]//div[@role='dialog']")):
            raise Exception("Failed to close our pop-up dialog")
    
  
  
# Gets our chrome driver and opens our site
chrome_driver = get_chrome_driver()
chrome_driver.get("https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/coffs-harbour_159102/schweppes-ken-howard-showcase-cup_913723/#OddsComparison")

close_dialog(chrome_driver)
wait_displayed(chrome_driver, "(//div[@class='oc-table-body'])[1]")
wait_displayed(chrome_driver, "//div[@class='header__container']//img[contains(@src, 'punterslogodesktop')]")
wait_displayed(chrome_driver, "//div[@class='form-header']//img[contains(@src,'coffsharbour.jpg')]")

# Get the number of displayed records
numOfRecords = chrome_driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='oc-table-body'])[1]//div[contains(@id, 'ocSelection')]").__len__()

# Scroll through each element and get the data
for num in range(numOfRecords):
    recordXpath = "(//div[@class='oc-table-body'])[1]//div[contains(@id, 'ocSelection')][{0}]".format(num + 1)
    scroll_to_element(chrome_driver, recordXpath)
    positionColor = chrome_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'{recordXpath}//div[@class="competitor-info "]//div[@class="result-icon"]').value_of_css_property('background-color')
    positionNumber = chrome_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'{recordXpath}//div[@class="competitor-info "]//div[@class="result-icon"]').text
    horseName = chrome_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'{recordXpath}//div[@class="competitor-details"]//span[contains(@class, "horse-name")]//a').get_attribute('rel').split("'s")[0]
    jockeyName = chrome_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'{recordXpath}//div[@class="competitor-details"]//span[contains(@class, "jockey-name")]//a').get_attribute('rel').split("'s")[0]
    bonusBetColor = chrome_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'{recordXpath}//span[contains(@data-key, "Average-FixedWin")]//span[contains(@class,"movement")]').value_of_css_property('color')
    bonusPercentage = chrome_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'{recordXpath}//span[contains(@data-key, "Average-FixedWin")]//span[contains(@class,"movement")]').text
    print("\nItem Number #{0}:".format(num + 2))
    print("Horse Name: {0}".format(horseName))
    print("Finishing Position: {0}".format(positionNumber))
    print("Finishing Position Color: {0}".format(positionColor))
    print("Jockey Name: {0}".format(jockeyName))
    print("Bonus Percentage: {0}".format(bonusPercentage))
    print("Bonus Color: {0}".format(bonusBetColor))
    print("=======================================================\n")

chrome_driver.quit()
chrome_driver.service.stop()
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT RESULT**

```
Item Number #2:
Horse Name: Our Gravano
Finishing Position: 1st
Finishing Position Color: rgba(71, 184, 72, 1)
Jockey Name: Hugh Bowman
Bonus Percentage: 8%
Bonus Color: rgba(75, 183, 72, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #3:
Horse Name: I'll Miss You
Finishing Position:
Finishing Position Color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
Jockey Name: Matthew McGuren
Bonus Percentage: 3%
Bonus Color: rgba(75, 183, 72, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #4:
Horse Name: Nistelrooy
Finishing Position:
Finishing Position Color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
Jockey Name: Jon Grisedale
Bonus Percentage: 0%
Bonus Color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #5:
Horse Name: Lamma Hilton
Finishing Position: 2nd
Finishing Position Color: rgba(39, 167, 223, 1)
Jockey Name: Tommy Berry
Bonus Percentage: 5%
Bonus Color: rgba(75, 183, 72, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #6:
Horse Name: Meteorologist
Finishing Position:
Finishing Position Color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
Jockey Name: Glen Boss
Bonus Percentage: 1%
Bonus Color: rgba(214, 55, 51, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #7:
Horse Name: Exilia Miss
Finishing Position:
Finishing Position Color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
Jockey Name: Peter Graham
Bonus Percentage: 1%
Bonus Color: rgba(214, 55, 51, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #8:
Horse Name: Winkler
Finishing Position:
Finishing Position Color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
Jockey Name: Noriyuki Masuda
Bonus Percentage: 1%
Bonus Color: rgba(75, 183, 72, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #9:
Horse Name: Husonique
Finishing Position:
Finishing Position Color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
Jockey Name: Brooke Stower
Bonus Percentage: 1%
Bonus Color: rgba(214, 55, 51, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #10:
Horse Name: Rage Against
Finishing Position:
Finishing Position Color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
Jockey Name: Matthew Paget
Bonus Percentage: 3%
Bonus Color: rgba(214, 55, 51, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #11:
Horse Name: Aberration
Finishing Position:
Finishing Position Color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
Jockey Name: Raymond Spokes
Bonus Percentage: 0%
Bonus Color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #12:
Horse Name: Mister Maker
Finishing Position:
Finishing Position Color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
Jockey Name: Ben Looker
Bonus Percentage: 0%
Bonus Color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #13:
Horse Name: Tan Tat Nova
Finishing Position:
Finishing Position Color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
Jockey Name: Tegan Harrison
Bonus Percentage: 2%
Bonus Color: rgba(214, 55, 51, 1)
=======================================================


Item Number #14:
Horse Name: Winged Poet
Finishing Position: 3rd
Finishing Position Color: rgba(39, 167, 223, 1)
Jockey Name: Jake Bayliss
Bonus Percentage: 0%
Bonus Color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 1)
=======================================================
```